# SID given in connect descriptor could not be established when connecting through the second listener

Tags: oracle10g, listener

I have a BI  10g database with 2 instances using listener port 1522.I configured a second listener using port 1521 the first listener uses port 1522.  When i try to connect to the database I get the SID given in connect descriptor could not be resolved

I have configured my listner.ora  to point to the database using port 1521  as well my tnsnames and when i to a lsnrctl serives I dont see both SIDs i only see PLSEctProc

when do a lsnrctl status I can only see the second listener with port 1521

is it possible to have 2 listeners listening to the same instances in the same server?

Answer (score 0):

Two listeners on a different port to the same database shouldn't be a problem.
Have you set the TNS_ADMIN parameter ? (pointing to another tnsnames.ora / listener.ora file)